# Generating C# code from XML: how to output '<' and '>'?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, code-generation

I have a XSLT that creates C# classes from XML. I'm using

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

to create a text file. Basically I took the code from http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch08_05.htm and modified it to output C# code.

But now I need to output something like

```
class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(obj => obj.LastName).NotEmpty();
        ...
    }
}
```

...but wherever I want to output '<' or '>' I get '&lt ;' and '&gt ;'.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

Here's my current XSLT (the CDATA don't work!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="className" select="/Class/@Name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="entityId" select="(//Property)[1]/@Name"/>     
    <xsl:template match="/Class">using System;
using System.Linq;
using Core.Common.Core;
using FluentValidation;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PersonDosimetry.Client.Entities.Constants
{
    public class <xsl:value-of select="$className"/>
       <xsl:text> : ObjectBase</xsl:text>
    {   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Property" mode="generateField"/>
        <xsl:text>      
        #region Business-mapped Properties  
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Property" mode="generateProperty"/>
        #endregion

        #region Validation

        class <xsl:value-of select="$className"/>Validator : AbstractValidator<![CDATA[<]]><xsl:value-of select="$className"/><![CDATA[>]]>
        {
            public <xsl:value-of select="$className"/>Validator()
            {               
                //RuleFor(obj =<![CDATA[>]]> obj.LastName).NotEmpty();
            }
        }

        protected override IValidator GetValidator()
        {
            return new <xsl:value-of select="$className"/>Validator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
</xsl:template>

    <!--
    *****************************************************************
    ** Generate a private field declaration.
    **************************************************************-->
    <xsl:template match="Property" mode="generateField"><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Type"/>
    <xsl:text> _</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>;
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
    *****************************************************************
    ** Generate a "get" method for a property.
    **************************************************************-->
    <xsl:template match="Property" mode="generateProperty">
        public <xsl:value-of select="@Type"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
        {
            get { return _<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>; }
            set
            {
                if (_<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/> != value)
                {
                    _<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/> = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Class Name="Person">
    <Property Name="PersonId" Type="Int32" />
    <Property Name="FirstNames" Type="String" />
    <Property Name="LastName" Type="String" />
    <Property Name="GenderTypeId" Type="Int32" />
    <Property Name="BirthDate" Type="DateTime" />
    <Property Name="InsuranceNumber" Type="String" />
    <Property Name="Country" Type="String" />
    <Property Name="Beruf" Type="String" />
</Class>
```

Comment: [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) would likely work best

Comment: Could you possibly show us the XSLT code you are currently trying to output the '<' or '>'? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, please show us your XSLT and tell us what XSLT processor you're using. If you're using `xsl:output method="text"`, then it should be easy to output `<` and `>`, unless you're using a substandard XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the XSLT processor I was using (the version from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8823/A-better-MSXSL-EXE-Adding-the-ability-to-Transform). I started using this since my code generator will need to process a couple of files and I was under the impression this does nothing different from MSXSL.

I downloaded [MSXSL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) and everything went smoothly using CDATA.

(A follow-up question would be: how can I do the correct transformation **programmatically** in .NET? Or is there a better XSL transformation library I can use?)

**Update**

The comment by JLRishe lead me in the right direction. I changed the above mentioned codeproject code to the following, and now the code generation works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have not entered the correct parameters");
            return;
        }
        string xmlfile = args[0];
        string xslfile = args[1];
        string outfile = args[2];
        try
        {
            XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(xmlfile);
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            transform.Load(xslfile);
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outfile, transform.OutputSettings);
            transform.Transform(doc, writer);
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In .NET, you should use the [XslCompiledTransform class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx). It supports embedded scripts if you need those for some reason. On a separate note, you should not need to use CDATA to accomplish this task. If you use `&lt;` and `&gt;` in your XSLT, they should be output as `<` and `>` as long as the output method is `text`.

Answer (score -2):

You should look into [Xml Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can convert your objects to xml and back to c# objects. This allows me to easily store any object as xml and quickly deserialize it back to an object.

for example, my object is called "MyObject":

```
public object DeserializeXmlMyObj(String xml)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

            MyObject obj = null;
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                obj = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            return obj ;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The question is about converting XML to C# *code*, it's not about de-/serializing objects.

Comment: @svick - understood, however, when you deserialize xml in the above example, it is creating c# objects. Although, it may not be a direct answer, it might be a solution that he/she didn't even consider. My intention was to encourage an alternate approach.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you're trying to generate C# classes that you could then use from your code, then some deserialized objects simply won't do.